# Windows 10 suddenly stops booting completely

Tags: boot, windows-10

This is going to beabit vague, but it's why I'm having the issue - I will provide all the details I am able to attain.

About 2 weeks ago, I cleanly installed windows 7, installed some programs, then upgraded to 10. Worked fine until this morning, where I turned on my computer and there was just a black screen. Forcibly restarted and then startup repair appears.

None of the options in startup repair work - startup repair couldn't resolve the problems, restarting with different options (including safemode) doesn't appear to do anything, there are no system restore points, pressing 'continue to windows 10' results in startup repair, pressing 'reset' with the option to keep personal data (intended toreinstall windoews) gets to onepercent then stops and says the computer could not reset.

I pressed revert to previous build, and while it has not crashed it is stuck on restarting and has been for thirty minutes.

What could have caused this complete failure of windows? Isit likely a hardware or software issue? Are there any ways of diagnosing further using cmd, which is the only tool I have access to? Any recommended next steps?

(Sorry for this.I am typing on my tablet, since I no longer have access to a computer.)

Comment: "Does it say restoring your previous version of Windows"?

Comment: It got stuck on just 'restarting'. I force restarted it and it now appears to be in an infinite restart loop of 'restoring previous version of windows' into a reboot. Looks like I will have to use a CD to install win7, but I'd still like to have some ideas of the cause of this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the bios to run off your windows 7 install disks and try to launch a repair or fresh install. I think windows decided to take a crap on your drive and corrupted itself. I had this issue when I was installing a windows 7 boot ssd.